# magento invoice customization

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am trying to modify the invoice generated when a customer places an order, so far I have generated the message a customer would attached along the gift and change its position, but i want to display the invoice number along with it and edit other components along with it.

```
$message = Mage::getModel('giftmessage/message');

    $gift_message_id = $invoice->getOrder()->getGiftMessageId();
    if(!is_null($gift_message_id)) {
          $message->load((int)$gift_message_id);
          $gift_sender = $message->getData('sender');
          $gift_recipient = $message->getData('recipient');
          $gift_message = $message->getData('message');


         $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__($gift_sender), 275, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
          $this->y -=10;

          $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__($gift_recipient), 275, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
          $this->y -=20;

          $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__($gift_message), 275, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
      }
```

this is the code calling the invoice number, how do i add it in the above code.

```
$this->insertDocumentNumber(
            $page,
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you placed the above mentioned code inside the `foreach` loop?

```
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
}
```

If this is the case than you can directly use the code that you have mentioned above

```
$this->insertDocumentNumber(
                    $page, Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
            );
```

You can see the above code just inserting the increment id retrieved from `$invoice->getIncrementId()` and placed it in `$page`.

If not than follow the use of  `protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)` in that file.This will give you the hint.

Hope this will help.

Comment: this did help, can i set it to coordinate 275, $this->y as well, like i did with others?

Comment: $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__ . $invoice->getIncrementId(), 275, $this->y, 'UTF-8' );                                                                          $this->y -=20;  i used the existing code and made some modifications to set the coordinates, this is how i did it.  thanks

Comment: I guess you could do so